# How can I capture the output from a shell command in Python?

Tags: python, subprocess

What I need to do is the following: in a Python script spawn, say the `ls --colors=always /` Linux command, and read its output. The important part of  this is that I need the output to keep all the ANSI escape sequences (colors and such) to later translate these sequences into HTML. I heard that Python `pty` module can do that, but I could not find a useful example of its usage in the Internet, and this module's documentation is not quite comprehensive. I'll appreciate if someone could guide me through the way of accomplishing this task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import subprocess as sub

process = sub.Popen("ls --colors=always /", stdout=sub.PIPE, stderr=sub.PIPE)
output, errors = process.communicate()
```

Now all the data you want should be in `output` - including the ANSI escape sequences.

Comment: Yes, this works for 'ls', but for some reason it does not work for Gentoo Linux 'emerge' command, which I actually need. When I call 'emerge -pvuDN world', it just strips all ANSI escapes and returns just plain text.

Comment: @Ch00k: I doubt it. Does it work __with the color codes__ for `ls`? I think `emerge` is not outputting colors if not used in an interactive shell. Try this: `emerge --colory -pvuDN world`.

Comment: You're right. I need to explicitly pass the '--color y' option to force colors on non-tty outputs. Thanks!